# Filter condition in MDX

Tags: filter, mdx

Hi could you please help me with MDX? I need to select measures for User count

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[User count]
     ,[Measures].[User count oM]
     ,[Measures].[User count oQ]
     ,[Measures].[User count oY]
    } ON COLUMNS
FROM [User count]
WHERE 
  (
    [Subscription tier].[Subscription tier].&[1]
   ,StrToMember("[Fordate].[YQMD].[Date].[" + Format(Now() - 1,"yyyy-MM-dd") + "]")
   ,{
      [Product].[Finance Group].&[3]
     ,[Product].[Finance Group].&[6]
     ,[Product].[Finance Group].&[8]
     ,[Product].[Finance Group].&[2]
     ,[Product].[Finance Group].&[9]
     ,[Product].[Finance Group].&[1]
    }
  );
```

This works. 
I need to add to this working MDX also condition like this:

```
if [Product].[Finance Group].&[1] then filter
[Version].[Version subgroup].&[AVG 2012] 
+[Version].[Version subgroup].&[AVG 2013] 
+[Version].[Version subgroup].&[AVG 2014] 
+[Version].[Version subgroup].&[AVG 2015]
+[Version].[Version subgroup].&[AVG 2016]
+[Version].[Version subgroup].&[AVG 7-10]
```

Comment: You can't simply "add" members of a dimension. Numeric operations are reserved for measures.

Comment: is that pseudo-code ?! what are your requirements for the condition? Can you state them in such a way so we understand the question please.

Comment: Sorry I´m new to MDX, so maybe my question is not clear...

I need to to have the condiotion WHERE for:
- subscription tier
- date
- finance group (3,6,8,2,9) and only finance group (1) must have another condition for version subgroup

Thank you.P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer. Maybe it will help somebody else:-)

```
with member [Version].[Version subgroup].[x] as
      [Version].[Version subgroup].&[AVG 2012]
     +[Version].[Version subgroup].&[AVG 2013]
     +[Version].[Version subgroup].&[AVG 2014]
     +[Version].[Version subgroup].&[AVG 2015]
     +[Version].[Version subgroup].&[AVG 2016]
     +[Version].[Version subgroup].&[AVG 7-10] 

    member a as
         ([Version].[Version subgroup].[x]
         ,[Measures].[User count])

    member a1 as
         ([Product].[Finance Group].&[1],a)

    member[Product].[Finance Group].[x] as
          [Product].[Finance Group].&[3]
         +[Product].[Finance Group].&[6]
         +[Product].[Finance Group].&[8]
         +[Product].[Finance Group].&[2]
         +[Product].[Finance Group].&[9]

    member b1 as
         ([Product].[Finance Group].[x]
         ,[Measures].[User count])

    member final as a1+b1

 SELECT
 NON EMPTY 
 {
  [Measures].[User count], 
  [Measures].[User count oM], 
  [Measures].[User count oQ], 
  [Measures].[User count oY]
 } ON COLUMNS
  FROM [User count]
  WHERE ([Subscription tier].[Subscription tier].&[1]
   , StrToMember("[Fordate].[YQMD].[Date].["+Format(Now()-1,"yyyy-MM-dd")+"]") 
   ,[User type].[User type].&[1]
     )
```